# Sublime Regex to replace everything other than numbers

Tags: regex, replace, numbers, sublimetext3, except

I have sample data

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
```

I want to remove everything else except numbers, keeping line `(\n)` as usually.

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

I am bit new to Sublime and Regex. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you can use the following.

```
Find: ^\D+|\D+$
Replace:
```

This matches the beginning of the string, followed by any character of *non-digits* (`1` or more times) **OR** any character of *non-digits* (`1` or more times) preceded by the end of the string.

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/fE7jH7)

Comment: +1 for the Live Demo. I played there for a while. Still Regex seems to be confusion to me. Assume, I want to replace only `|<one or more spaces>` and `<one or more spaces>|`. nothing else should be replaced. how do I do that.

Comment: You could do `^\|\s+|\s+\|$` or `\|\s+(\d+)\s+\|` and replace with `\1`

Comment: Got it. I tried by my own hand '\\|+|\\s+' :) Really helpful site

Comment: if there's zero space between `|` and any other character, it's not removing. how can i include that too

Comment: Instead of `+` use `*` meaning `0` or more times

Answer (score 3):

Open the Find Replace in Sublime. You'll search for:

`[^\d\n]+`

and replace with an empty string.

The Regex matches everything except numbers or newlines

Comment: If you add a `+` afterwards, the regex is more efficient

Comment: Wow. thanks. If I want to exclude commas too, how do I change this one! I am actually writing big macro for my need :)

Comment: Add the comma into the `[...]` brackets: `[^\d\n,]+`